# ActionController::ParameterMissing (Param is missing or the value is empty) in Controller Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and working to build an app for parents giving tasks(mission) to there children.

But when I try to update the task by changing the status, I get : param is missing or the value is empty: mission

Mission :

```
create_table "missions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "point"
    t.date "start_at"
    t.date "end_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_missions_on_user_id"
end
```

Model :

```
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  enum status: [:to_do, :pending, :done]
end
```

My controller :

```
class MissionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_mission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    # @mission.update(params[:id])
    @mission.update(mission_params)
  end

private

  def set_mission
    @mission = Mission.find(params[:id])
    authorize @mission
  end

  def mission_params
    params.require(:mission).permit(:user_id, :start_at, :end_at, :point, :name, status: [:to_do, :pending, :done])
  end
```

My mission_show

```
  <%= simple_form_for @mission do |f| %>
    <% f.input :status, value: 1 %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

Here my error message :

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in MissionsController#update 
param is missing or the value is empty: mission
```

```
@mission
=> <Mission id: 2, name: "guest room", point: 3, start_at: "2019-03-16", end_at: "2019-05-16", created_at: "2019-04-09 12:12:25", updated_at: "2019-04-09 12:12:25", user_id: 5, status: "to_do">


params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"FYn7UAPJ7u+zQCcd+nNXUlEc2+NAWrdBWHhtfN2UPmex0kcG3VrgPUcIjDxdsmmA54DO/ee0Ks1XbGAtiR7tHw==", "commit"=>"Update Mission", "controller"=>"missions", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2"} permitted: false>
```

I've already tryed every solution I could find, but none of them seemed to work for me. 
Thanks

Comment: "when I try to update the task by changing the status" - how are you doing that if there's no text field on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form doesn't have any inputs. Do this instead:

```
 <%= f.input :status, value: 1 %>
```